# Tricks, Tips and Nontrivial Insights with Higher-Order Functions

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, functional-programming

*Many* years ago I briefly skimmed a physical book (or perhaps a preprint?) on programming in Racket that included lots of really unique uses of `map` and `fold` (`reduce`) in particular, although it had plenty of genuinely unique tricks with curried (curryed?) functions et al. -- all of these without (notable) loss of generality across language.

I distinctly recall amazingly tiny and elegant ways to traverse and manipulate trees, produce huffman encodings, generate a min/max heap and much more. If my memory serves, many of them relied on folding up a function (e.g, the value being accumulated and ultimately returned was an anonymous function), ultimately there was some very general and nontrivial rule concerning `map` and `fold` individually that was rooted in computer science.

In trying to scrape my brain for the list all I came up with was a very lame rehashed version of a recursive function to extract the leaves from a tree.

```cl
(define-fn get-leaves
     (mapc (lambda g 
           (print g#value)
           get-leaves) 
     graphs)
```

alternatively

```js
function getLeaves(node) {
  if (node.children == null) console.log(node.value);
  else node.children.map(getLeaves)
}
```

If someone knows the name of this article or book, that would be the absolute greatest.

If not, I'd love a list of unique and powerful insights or snippets involving map/fold or otherwise related concepts.

*I'll ask the reader to omit the generic uses of `map` and `reduce` (apply-to or summing of lists, building an associative array, etc) that most are already familiar with*

Comment: Almost any decent Scheme book should cover this in depth.

Comment: I guess a reference requestion for a *programming* would be more successful on [SO] or [programmers.SE]. You second, very different query for "list of unique and powerful insights or snippets involving map/fold or otherwise related concepts" is far too broad for a single SE question.

Comment: Have you looked at [functional pearls](https://wiki.haskell.org/Research_papers/Functional_pearls)?  (Still accepting [new submissions](https://wiki.haskell.org/Research_papers/Functional_pearls))

Comment: These `tricks` you're talking about and that `rule` you mentioned are discussed here: http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/files/3390/PRG69.pdf ; Bird is an excellent expositor; these notes use notation that is not associated with any programming language. Enjoy!!